# Testflight Invitations doesn't sent to internal testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm having an issue with invites not being sent out to internal testers. Usually, I just have to invalidate the build, upload a new one (with a higher build number) and then fill in the missing compliance and the invites would get sent immediately.

However, as of today, it seems like no invites are being sent and if I look under "App store connect users" each row has "No Builds Available" under status even though there is a build available:
1.0  (10) "Ready to Test
Expires in 89 days"

Comment: make sure that your tester has valid apple email id.

Comment: @iNiravKotecha I'm sure that everything is ok. And it was working till yesterday.

Comment: do you received any email from apple regarding your last build ?

Comment: @iNiravKotecha Yes I do. Sir, I found a solution and I just want to share with others!

Answer (score 0):

- As of now (Feb 11 8:30 AM GMT), providing export compliance in
  app store connect still DOES NOT WORK
- Adding the export compliance
  to info.plist works

See [steps to automate the "Export Compliance"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations)